# How can i make my jQuery code work on all elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, accordion

I have this accordion menu but it only works on the first `ul`. How do I get it to work on all `ul` like this? If you could explain what I'm doing wrong so I know in the future that would be great.

Also, how do I get it so that the link toggles between two classes, `right` and `down` each time it is clicked? It also has the class `turq-font` on it. I want the `right` to be removed and replaced with `down` when the link is clicked and the menu is showing. Heres my code:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#show-menu").click(function() {
    $("#sub-menu-acc").toggleClass("active-menu", 1000);
  });
});
```

```css
.active-menu {
  display: block !important;
}
.admin-area ul li {
  margin: 6px 0px;
}
.admin-right-menu ul li a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.admin-area ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.admin-area ul li ul {
  display: none;
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="admin-area">
<div class="admin-right-menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" id="show-menu" class="turq-font right">Stats ></a>
      <ul id="sub-menu-acc">
        <li><a href="#">Business Stats</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Affiliate stats</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" id="show-menu" class="turq-font right">Reports ></a>
      <ul id="sub-menu-acc">
        <li><a href="#">Global</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sales</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sales trends</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to your use of repeated `id` attributes; they should be unique within a `document`. Convert your code to use classes instead.

Also note that you should use the `this` keyword to traverse the DOM to find the `ul` related to the clicked `a` element, and the addition of `right down` in a `toggleClass()` call. Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".show-menu").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the '#' of the clicked a appearing in the URL 
    $(this).toggleClass('right down').next(".sub-menu-acc").toggleClass("active-menu");
  });
});
```

```css
.active-menu {
  display: block !important;
}
.admin-area ul li {
  margin: 6px 0px;
}
.admin-right-menu ul li a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.admin-area ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.admin-area ul li ul {
  display: none;
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="admin-area">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="show-menu turq-font right">Stats ></a>
      <ul class="sub-menu-acc">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Business Stats</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Affiliate stats</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="show-menu turq-font right">Reports ></a>
      <ul class="sub-menu-acc">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Global</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Sales</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Sales trends</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. Do you know how I can switch the Right class to Down when that link is clicked? Could you explain it so I understand it in the future if possible.

Comment: I just updated my answer to cover that; you can just add those classes to the `toggleClass()` call.